# Odd Number Probability

Tags: probability, odds

How do I calculate the probability of randomly picking a number in the range from 0 to 10000 where exactly two of the digits is odd. For ex 5001 or 1010 etc.. and how would I do the same calculation for a range that starts with an odd number for ex 10000 to 20000?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can e.g. treat $5000$ as $05000$ the condition that the left one has exactly 2 odd digits is equivalent to the condition that the right one has 2 odd digits, because 0 is even.

The process of drawing a random number out of $\{0,1, ..., 10000\}$ is therefore equivalent to drawing once from a distribution that has probability $10000/10001$ for 0 and $1/10001$ for 1 and 4 times from a uniform distribution over $\{0, ..., 9\}$ and ordering these numbers.

We therefore look for the probability that exactly two of these 5 digits are odd.

The probability for the first digit to be odd is $1/10001$ and for the other 4 digits the probability for being odd is $0.5$ and order doesnt matter, therefore the probability you are looking for is:

$$ 10000/10001\cdot0.5^4 \cdot {{4}\choose{2}}$$

If you get a 1 for the left digit you cannot get two odd Digits because the maximal number is 10000 If you get a 0 for the left digit you need two odd digits out of the remaining 4 which is the above term

Comment: not sure, but i think this might cause a little bias because not all digits have 5/10 chance beeing odd. 
The one on the most lefthand side has a chance of beeing odd of 5/9 and 4/9 for beeing even, since the leading digit of a number cant be zero (or if we allow zero it will allways be a non odd number, which results in the same). 
so i guess you'd have to split this all up in 2 different approaches for each number with more than 1 digit.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct.  It should equal 3750/10001, which is approximately 0.3749625.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to solve this using R, since im not very good with mathematic notations.

```
test = 0:10000
test = data.frame(test)
length(test$test)

# 10001 different numbers are possible
# x of them fulfill the requirement of 2 odd digits.
# find x

amount_of_digits = table(nchar(as.character(test$test)))

# Based on chance.
# x out y do fulfill our criterion. So x/y * total number = number of cases we are looking for
# 1 digit -> zero chance to get 2 digits odd -> 0 out of 10
# 2 digits -> 1-9_0-9 -> both have to be odd -> 5/9*5/10 * 90 = 25 out of 90
5/9*5/10*90
# 3 digits -> 1-9_0-9_0-9 -> 2 out of 3 have to be odd -> 350 out of 900
5/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 900
5/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 900
4/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 900
5/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 900 + 5/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 *900 + 4/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 900
# 4 digits -> 1-9_0-9_0-9_0-9 -> 3375
4/9 * (5/10 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 9000) * 3 # first one beeing even and 2 out of 3 of the following are odd
5/9 * (5/10 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 9000) * 3 # first one beeing odd and 1 out of 3 of the following is odd
4/9 * (5/10 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 9000) * 3 + 5/9 * (5/10 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 9000) * 3
# 5 digits -> 10000 only 1 possible number which doesnt fulfill the requirements -> zero out of 1

# all together: 3750 out of 10000
0 +
5/9*5/10*90 +
5/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 900 + 5/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 *900 + 4/9 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 900 +
4/9 * (5/10 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 9000) * 3 + 5/9 * (5/10 * 5/10 * 5/10 * 9000) * 3 +
0


# this can be shortened down to a "amount based approach" instead of a chance based one too
# instead of saying: x/y * total number, we just look for x - this way we do not need the total amount of possibilitys
# but this only work if we can use the ful range of possible digis for each digit-space of the number
# like from 0 to 100, 0 to 1000 and so on. wont work for 15 to 210 cause here we can not use all the
# possible digits on the far right side digit
0 +
5*5 + # there are 5 different numbers in the first spot which can be combined with 5 different numbers in the second spot
5 * 5 * 5 + 5 * 5 * 5 + 4 * 5 * 5 +
4 * (5 * 5 * 5) * 3 + 5 * (5 * 5 * 5) * 3 +
0


# lets check if we are right. 

# function to count the odd digits in the numbers
# this gets pretty slow if number of digits get large
count_odd_digits = function(number)
{
  temp = unlist(strsplit(as.character(number), ""))
  sum_odd_digits = sum(temp %in% c(1,3,5,7,9))
  return(sum_odd_digits)
}

test$sum_odd_digits = NA
test$sum_odd_digits = apply(test, 1, count_odd_digits)

# how many of our digits have 2 odds
table(test$sum_odd_digits == 2)



# lets try to generalize this

# things we know
# each digit has 5/10 odds and 5/10 evens
# for all numbers having more than 1 digit:
# the most leftside digit of the number has a chance of 5/9 beeing odd and 4/9 beeing even
# for all numbers having 2 exactly 2 digits:
# the left side digit has to be odd to get a hit. all numbers with not odd leftside digit wont cause a hit

# the formula:
number_digits = 2 # change the desired number of digits here
(5 * 5^(number_digits - 1)  * (number_digits-1)) + # this gives the amount of possible numbers starting with a leading odd digit in the far left
  ifelse(number_digits <3,0,(4 * 5^(number_digits-1) * factorial(number_digits - 1)/(2*factorial(number_digits-1-2)))) # this gives the amount of numbers starting with an even digit on the far left side. Since a number with 2 digits only has to start with a leading odd digit to can have 2 odd digits total ive included the ifelse here.

# for 1 to 10000

number_digits = 2
amount2_digits = (5 * 5^(number_digits - 1)  * (number_digits-1)) + 
  ifelse(number_digits <3,0,(4 * 5^(number_digits-1) * factorial(number_digits - 1)/(2*factorial(number_digits-1-2))))

number_digits = 3
amount3_digits = (5 * 5^(number_digits - 1)  * (number_digits-1)) + 
  ifelse(number_digits <3,0,(4 * 5^(number_digits-1) * factorial(number_digits - 1)/(2*factorial(number_digits-1-2))))

number_digits = 4
amount4_digits = (5 * 5^(number_digits - 1)  * (number_digits-1)) + 
  ifelse(number_digits <3,0,(4 * 5^(number_digits-1) * factorial(number_digits - 1)/(2*factorial(number_digits-1-2))))

total = amount2_digits + amount3_digits + amount4_digits



test = 1:10000
test = data.frame(test)

# function to count the odd digits in the numbers
count_odd_digits = function(number)
{
  temp = unlist(strsplit(as.character(number), ""))
  sum_odd_digits = sum(temp %in% c(1,3,5,7,9))
  return(sum_odd_digits)
}

test$sum_odd_digits = NA
test$sum_odd_digits = apply(test, 1, count_odd_digits)

# how many of our digits have 2 odds
table(test$sum_odd_digits == 2)
```

Comment: Try this: `odd <- "[13579]";
other <- "[02468]*";
mean(grepl(paste0("^", other, odd, other, odd, other, "$"), sprintf("%d", 0:1e4)))`

Comment: whuber, thats sexy! But i dont understand why/how it works. Could you be so nice to explain why this: ^[02468]*[13579][02468]*[13579][02468]*$ "counts" as a 2 odd digit number in a 4-digits long number?

Comment: It's a regular expression to match precisely two odd digits, with any numbers of even digits sprinkled around them.